# Tkinter config from a different class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have shortened my code to 100 lines but in a much larger file I cannot properly use the config function to change a label in a different class. If you run my file here you will see I am attempting to change 0 to a different str value.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Tk):'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        #declare our frame
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #Setup the frame
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        #declare the object to hold the frames
        self.frames = {}

        #loop through the list of frames
        for i in (Page_One, Page_Two):
            frame = i(container, self)
            self.frames[i] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        #start with the home page
        self.show_frame(Page_One)

    def show_frame(self, context):
        '''This method will show the frame that is passed through it. \n
        Used in button by implementing lamda'''

        frame = self.frames[context]
        frame.tkraise()


class Page_One(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        def change_value(value):
            Page_Two.label.config(text = value)
            print(value)

        Button(self, text='Set value to 1',command=lambda *args: change_value('1')).pack()
        Button(self, text='Set value to 2',command=lambda *args: change_value('2')).pack()
        Button(self, text='Set value to 3',command=lambda *args: change_value('3')).pack()
        Button(self, text='Page 2', command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page_Two)).pack()


class Page_Two(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = Label(self, text = '0')
        label.pack()

        Button(self, text='Page 1',command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page_One)).pack()


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory. Are you aware of the difference between local variables (eg: `label`) and instance variables (eg: `self.label`)?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am familiar however i am not sure what you mean, would you mind elaborating? I am basically trying to change the label in Page_Two class from a method in Page_One class

Comment: You've defined `label` as a local variable, so it's only available inside `Page_Two.__init__`.